# Network usage of file open and seek in distributed filesystem like ceph

Tags: ceph, distributed-filesystem

When I open a file stored in another node in a distributed filesystem and just read the 100 bytes. Does the filesystem try to "prefetch" more data to my node? E.g., The network traffic for sending the file is more than 100 bytes.

Another question is if I seek to the end of the file stored in another node. Does the distributed file system try to send the entire file to me? Or there is no network usage for transferring the file since only the pointer to the position in the file changed?